# How to open modal and show content using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new too javascript, but I have watched may tutorial on js, so I create a simple footer, but when the user clicks on like subscribe then open the modal and show the content within it

I have researched the internet for a solution, but nothing is working.

HTML

```
<footer ng-controller="Footerng-controller" class=" hidden-xxs hidden-xs hidden-sm root">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container row">
            <ul class="social">
                <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/Galaxygames" class="facebook" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="Facebook"></a></li>

                <li><a href="http://twitter.com/GalaxyGames" class="twitter" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="Twitter"></a></li>

                <li><a href="http://instagram.com/Galaxygames" class="instagram" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="Instagram"></a></li>

                <li><a href="http://youtube.com/Galaxygames" class="youtube" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="YouTube"></a></li>

                <li><a href="http://twitch.tv/Galaxygames" class="twitch" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Click" data-gtm-label="Twitch"></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="links">
                <li><a href="#" class="subscribe" click="toggleSection('subscribe')">Subscribe</a></li>




<li><a href="#" class="subscribe" click="toggleSection('subscribe')">Subscribe</a></li>

<div id="subscribe" class="subscribe-wrapper col-xxs-12">
  <div class="subscribe">
    <dl class="row">
      <dt class="col-xs-12">Subscribe to the Galaxy Mailing List</dt>
      <dd class="col-xs-12">Welcome to the Galaxy Games Subscription Management page. Galaxy mailing lists are the best way to get the early word on all our game announcements, official launches, contests, special events, and more. Make sure you're enlisted to receive all
        the updates.</dd>
    </dl>
    <a href="https://socialclub.galaxy-games.co.uk/settings/email" class="manage" target="_blank" click="closeSection()" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Club" data-gtm-label="Manage Subscription Account">Manage Your Account</a>
    <div click="closeSection()" class="close">x</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("subscribe");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("subscribe")[0];

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
 modal.style.display = "none";
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>







                <li><a href="http://support.galaxy-games.co.uk/" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Support">Support</a></li>

                <li><a href="/careers" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Careers">Careers</a></li>

                <li><a href="#" class="mouthoff" click="toggleSection('mouthoff')">Mouthoff</a></li>

                <li><a href="#" class="press" click="toggleSection('press')">Press</a></li>

                <li><a href="/corpinfo" ui-sref="corpinfo" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Corporate Info">Corporate</a></li>

                <li><a href="/privacy" ui-sref="privacy" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Privacy">Privacy</a></li>

                <li><a href="/cookies" target="_self" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Privacy">Cookies</a></li>

                <li><a href="/legal" ui-sref="legal" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Legal">Legal</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="language">
                <div click="toggleSection('language')" class="{active: currentSection === &quot;language&quot;}" id="language-current">
                    <span class="en_us">English</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Galaxy"><a href="/" ui-sref="home" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Home">
                <img src="/img/global/Galaxy.svg" alt=""></a>
                <ul>
                    <li>New York</li>
                    <li>London</li>
                    <li>Paris</li>
                    <li>Bogota</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="{active: currentSection === &quot;language&quot;}" class="language-selector"><ul>
            <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=en_us" target="_self" data-language="en">English</a></li>

            <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=de_de" target="_self" data-language="de">Deutsch</a></li>

            <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=fr_fr" target="_self" data-language="fr">Français</a></li>

            <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=it_it" target="_self" data-language="it">Italiano</a></li>

            <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=ja_jp" target="_self" data-language="ja" class="bold">日本語</a></li>

            <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=ru_ru" target="_self" data-language="ru">РУССКИЙ</a></li>

            <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=es_es" target="_self" data-language="es">ESPAÑOL (ESPAÑA)</a></li>

            <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=es_mx" target="_self" data-language="es-mx">ESPAÑOL (MÉXICO)</a></li>

            <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=pt_br" target="_self" data-language="pt">PORTUGUÊS</a></li>

            <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=ko_kr" target="_self" data-language="ko">한국어</a></li>

            <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=zh_hans" target="_self" data-language="zh-hans" class="bold">中文（简体）</a></li>

            <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=zh_tw" target="_self" data-language="zh" class="bold">中文（繁體）</a></li>

            <li><a href="/language-selector/selector/change?currentLocaleBase=%2F&amp;newLocale=pl_pl" target="_self" data-language="pl">POLSKI</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="subscribe-wrapper col-xxs-12">
    <div class="subscribe">
        <dl class="row">
            <dt class="col-xs-12">Subscribe to the Galaxy Mailing List</dt>
            <dd class="col-xs-12">Welcome to the Galaxy Games Subscription Management page. Galaxy mailing lists are the best way to get the early word on all our game announcements, official launches, contests, special events, and more. Make sure you're enlisted to receive all the updates.</dd></dl>
            <a href="https://socialclub.galaxy-games.co.uk/settings/email" class="manage" target="_blank" click="closeSection()" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Club" data-gtm-label="Manage Subscription Account">Manage Your Account</a>
            <div click="closeSection()" class="close"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mouthoff-wrapper col-xxs-12">
        <div class="mouthoff-markup row scope">
            <div id="mouthoff" ng-controller="Mouthoffng-controller" class="mouthoff col-xxs-12 scope">
                <dl class="col-xxs-12">
                    <dt>Mouthoff - Tell Us What's On Your Mind</dt>
                    <p>Have something you want to tell us, ask us or bring to our attention? Feel free to Mouthoff and let us know here. Please bear in mind that we may not be able to answer absolutely everything and we won’t reveal to you any game info that hasn't yet been announced, but we’re always happy to have a look at what you have to say.</p><p>If you have a technical issue that you’d like to report, please <a href="http://www.galaxy-games.co.uk/support" target="_blank">contact our Support Team</a>.</p><dd>
                        <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="row common-form pristine valid" action="https://www.galaxy-games.co.uk/mouthoff/mouthoff/submit.json">
                            <div style="display:none;">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" autocomplete="off"></div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-5 col-xxs-12">
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Name" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide your name')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required="required" id="name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-5 col-xxs-12">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email Address" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide your email address')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required="required" id="email" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xxs-12">
                                    <label for="age">Age</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="age" class="form-control" min="13" max="100" pattern="[0-9]{2}" placeholder="Age" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide your age')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required="required" id="age">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-xxs-12">
                                    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Subject" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide a subject')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required="required" id="subject">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xxs-12">
                                    <select name="category_id" required="required" id="category-id">
                                        <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                        <option value="1">General Suggestions</option>
                                        <option value="2">GTA Online Suggestions</option>
                                        <option value="3">Crews</option>
                                        <option value="4">Other Social Club Features</option>
                                        <option value="5">Galaxy Warehouse</option>
                                        <option value="6">Customer Support</option>
                                        <option value="7">Other Feedback</option>
                                        <option value="8">Check out my Job</option>
                                        <option value="9">Check out my Fan Video</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-xxs-12">
                                    <textarea name="body" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Talk To Us" templates="<div class=&quot;form-group col-xxs-12&quot;></div>" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide content')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" maxlength="5000" required="required"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div id="captcha">
                                    <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
                                        <div>
                                            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LejXR0TAAAAAOmd4Ya4FwOMyQar9uGCYU3Qm6P9&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucm9ja3N0YXJnYW1lcy5jb206NDQz&amp;hl=en&amp;v=v1563777128698&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=7eh5s8ewvd10" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-yc8avbksowkq" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe>
                                        </div>
                                        <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="g-response" autocomplete="off">
                                <button class="btn btn-yellow" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                                <!-- ngIf: message -->
                            </form>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div click="closeSection()" class="close"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="press-wrapper col-xxs-12">
                <div class="press">
                    <dl class="row">
                        <dt class="col-xs-12">Press - Contact our Public Relations Department</dt>
                    </dl>
                    <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="row common-form pristine valid" action="https://www.galaxy-games.co.uk/official/press-form.json">
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" autocomplete="off"></div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xxs-12">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Name" required="required" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide your name')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" id="name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xxs-12">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email Address" required="required" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide your email address')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" id="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-xxs-12">
                                <textarea name="press" class="form-control" id="press" rows="4" placeholder="Talk To Us" templates="<div class=&quot;form-group col-xs-12&quot;></div>" required="required" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You need to provide content')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" maxlength="5000"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div id="captchaPress">
                                <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
                                    <div>
                                        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LejXR0TAAAAAOmd4Ya4FwOMyQar9uGCYU3Qm6P9&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucm9ja3N0YXJnYW1lcy5jb206NDQz&amp;hl=en&amp;v=v1563777128698&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=9x270nn4bpg8" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-prvxu65bqsc0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                    <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response-1" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="g-response-press" autocomplete="off">
                                <button class="btn btn-yellow" type="submit" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Press Form Submit" data-gtm-label="">SUBMIT</button>
                                <!-- ngIf: messagePress -->
                            </form>
                            <div click="closeSection()" class="close"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
```

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiLhb.jpg

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: please post valid HTML. You can check for valid HTML on https://validator.w3.org

Comment: Likely you are using Bootstrap. Why not using the modal from Bootstrap? Or is it for learning purpose only? Bootstrap 3 modal https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp and Bootstrap 4 modal https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: You use `getElementById("subscribe")` yet there aren't any elements with `id="subscribe"` attribute. Also, no two elements should have the same id. (modal and btn in your case)

Answer (score 1):

In below code i have given `id` to your modal div ,also i didn't find any `id` with name `subscribe` in your above code but there is `class` with that name change that as well . Working code :

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("subscribe");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("subscribe")[0];

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
 modal.style.display = "none";
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#" class="subscribe" click="toggleSection('subscribe')">Subscribe</a></li>

<div id="subscribe" class="subscribe-wrapper col-xxs-12">
  <div class="subscribe">
    <dl class="row">
      <dt class="col-xs-12">Subscribe to the Galaxy Mailing List</dt>
      <dd class="col-xs-12">Welcome to the Galaxy Games Subscription Management page. Galaxy mailing lists are the best way to get the early word on all our game announcements, official launches, contests, special events, and more. Make sure you're enlisted to receive all
        the updates.</dd>
    </dl>
    <a href="https://socialclub.galaxy-games.co.uk/settings/email" class="manage" target="_blank" click="closeSection()" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Club" data-gtm-label="Manage Subscription Account">Manage Your Account</a>
    <div click="closeSection()" class="close">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What didn't work ? did you got any error ? did you run above code snippet ?

Comment: Yea I ran the above code, but when i click on the button to open the modal, then the page just refreshes. I have updated the above code for the entire footer :/

Comment: you didn't add `id` to `<div class="subscribe-wrapper col-xxs-12">` just change it to `<div id="subscribe" class="subscribe-wrapper col-xxs-12">`

Comment: Okay the above code has been update with the changes

Comment: Does that worked ? did your console shows any error ?

Comment: No it didn't work and there are no errors relating to the modal in the console

Comment: You have written two times this -> `<li><a href="#" class="subscribe" click="toggleSection('subscribe')">Subscribe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="subscribe" click="toggleSection('subscribe')">Subscribe</a></li>` in above code remove one and check again .

Answer (score 0):

Some id's and classes seems to be mixed up. An id can only be used once, thus the id `subscribe` can only be used once. Classes can be used to reuse a identifier. An working example with updated ids can be found below:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<li><a href="https://socialclub.galaxy-games.co.uk/settings/email" target="_blank" data-gtm-category="Mobile Nav" data-gtm-action="Link Click" data-gtm-label="Subscribe">Subscribe</a></li>

<li><a href="#" id="subscribe">Subscribe safe</a></li>

<div class="subscribe-wrapper col-xxs-12">
    <div id="modal" style="display: none">
        <dl class="row">
            <dt class="col-xs-12">Subscribe to the Galaxy Mailing List</dt>
            <dd class="col-xs-12">Welcome to the Galaxy Games Subscription Management page. Galaxy mailing lists are the best way to get the early word on all our game announcements, official launches, contests, special events, and more. Make sure you're enlisted to receive all the updates.</dd></dl>
        <a href="https://socialclub.galaxy-games.co.uk/settings/email" class="manage" target="_blank" click="closeSection()" data-gtm-category="Footer" data-gtm-action="Social Club" data-gtm-label="Manage Subscription Account">Manage Your Account</a>
        <div click="closeSection()" class="close">CLOSE</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("subscribe");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target !== btn) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing has changed as when clicked, then the modal still does not open :/

Comment: Did you click on Subscribe safe? @KyleLogan

Comment: Yeah I clicked on Subscribe Safe

Comment: Can you replace your entire html file by the example provided above? The above examples shows/hides the "Subscribe to the Galaxy..." section. Try using a hard-refresh(ctrl F5). You will need to provided more context if this still fails. @KyleLogan

Comment: It is really hard to help if you only mention that it doesn't work. What part doesn't work? Does more text show if you click "Subscribe safe" in the following demo: https://jsfiddle.net/maartendev/arytcn3h/

Comment: No, Nothing happens

Comment: Define "nothing", does it show any errors in the console(f12)? What browser are you using? Does it show any text at all? @KyleLogan

Comment: no errors in the console. I'm using google chrome and it doesn't show any text at all

Comment: Does it show "Subscribe" and "Subscribe safe" links in the above demo(https://jsfiddle.net/maartendev/arytcn3h/)? @KyleLogan

Comment: What happens when you click on "Subscribe safe"? Can you try it in another browser and ensure you have javascript enabled? @KyleLogan

Comment: It also doesn't work on another browser and javascript is enabled

Comment: It works on my side, i can't help you without any further information. Can you provide a https://jsfiddle.net demo with the code that doesn't work? @KyleLogan

Comment: Please simplify your demo, it contains way too much noise and is really slow. I won't fix your entire application, provide a small concrete example of your problem. @KyleLogan

Comment: There seems to be an css issue, i fixed it here: https://jsfiddle.net/maartendev/2yer36dx/5/ . I the following properties from `footer.root .subscribe-wrapper`: `bottom:100%;` and `max-height: 0` @KyleLogan

Comment: Thank you, but it refreshes the page and appears. Like i would like it like this example: https://imgur.com/Yf1Qvwb :/

Comment: @KyleLogan if you want to show it on page load, remove the default display none? https://jsfiddle.net/maartendev/2yer36dx/8/